# TypeScript problem to infer constrained generic arguments through a generic function itself

Tags: typescript, function, generics, constants

Demoed through this [TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcCcE8EsDsDmED2oDGkCmBDcXQdQAzAV3nXFhXggAs9D10sAHcAZ3oIBE8iE%20SMRwsAdACgQ3UH3AD4QkS1AATLEIC2CLFyIcNoFMVAADPFFgAjUvg6nQANxwAbUroA0heKu61XLigA7lwIoLCcZhykVgbgDqyQKKxYkODQ4eBG8C4ZAcF6oNGxhsbcBoTgljZ2ktLgdLBcQSiQANbNWC4uoEF0WLSsOBwcCMhEpqr8DjiQiKSaA1mCaEQAwgCSAGK9-dgys-OLiuFcAFakHFlErC44YShWZ1iUdWARaii68ADkWS3tXYDGSTaaEOYLJanQigTY7BqMbDgUiQeCFMgUKg0UAACgRWSRKLR9EYt3utEez0oAEpJBJBKllLx%20AAeAAqAEEqpBrLYCFgAB74HxcK48pCgAC8RUsSAAfKAAN4SUCq0DYHCqGi5SrVPkcABc6twWpyGU53N5%20AA2gBdFVqjWmnXFOJGi16-CgQXC1SheDEVKgACqoAA-MbNdqMsG7aAjfAsI5UhIAL4SKQgLPZnO5vP5guFovFkul0sZ6RBCJ0FC2GEYyjUfwQ45ZAC09CavVaHRIOgzDaxtCm8gAcigtuR0OyuZ7%20UKBn6ZeLEHKcSOcEa5DgZ5aalg5dSt6yPTz9wrlWrjcjUWp%20GmM%20gaFdQIgUChVOPJxQpXexxOpxxRVdTPfUjWtH4cB%20LwfisH5bS8V0NHAyD4NTalM1AAB1AB5AAlABpABlI1BRSSgsF8VIkkgbIohiOIHGjUAO0mBwu3gFAsiGNIjBMcwmNo0wrFMCQnzRLIrE1L8p1-DcZIoICQKtXQUKgmC4IQooGOQ0AINUNCMMzMsTNMszzIs4sKzAKsGnrKch3BI4oQ7D4tW%20P4Bwcps-xwLDq2-adxJfNlAscn1Fy4HEcWpKUFW3ak1w3MKm3dFKaCPUBQu87FL0dDQiV89L4AfMTnyyN8P38hpArk-hqroQLotiyUFSUixQLsNToNAWD4MQnTwG6210Iw6QeBwgBRIjRx%20NlsPwgjSIFcj8CoyAaLo0wkPibIdVY1R2K4TjuNmLIygEowhJEsqJNAKTVAa2rpQ3J7AJiuLcWAjqVMNPTUI0-rtJKIb-oMkbqSMyzoZh2G4ezazQBrZMVyMFGzFegKp3YgNqMo18BlSWB0C4aBawwHBaAMAgGhp6AUi4C7TxUo7fmWXGNvxxgAlxSmqJFUBSFYe6sDGGExTGWlMKCAh0EpiAYCKFAXEcMWPisDJNBwNoxdp68iXxwcfIiAwXBMRBCZ5dBCE6bpcVsugZETIIzGC3a2iwaAAVUWKwj1nilh%20LgLcTK2nMhE51GIBAIlSxG2wTxOk%20TlPU7T9PU4VUdJqw0AAHFJuzvDJo2NZQAAIUmgAZHDc4kI3sUxmqpw5Hw88t4mWTdrLiu9BcBZxLvyqyvvfVFWVEC8PC1xa%20KT0PJL%20GKtKcvgTLssxHy8tVQlb2S1fSvGqaZrmhbCNAUda9ADkiOw6uq9kYNJqynDQCI4Ny7ZABNAAFZ%20NiIu-Sat0XyVUeljCgrdVDt1DsTOq8g3qQLbh3dAzVPrtT3GBf66leqaQGiDYaqYbYYHKpDTCE1pqzXmrhQiy1Vr42oq0LaO0mJmhYhjI6oATqgB4udfiOBBJmBut3B6iD0BQJgUTa2L16oQPEcg2BqCPqtS%20spfcf0II4L6lpHaKFwajSAA).

I'm trying to create a function that accepts the a constrained interface:

```js
interface Data<TAttribute extends string = string> {
    readonly attributes: readonly TAttribute[]
    readonly subset: TAttribute extends infer U ? readonly U[] : never
}
```

The Data interface determines a set of `attributes` values, and then allows in its `subset` property it only allows a subset of these attributes. This works well when passing a `data` argument into a the function where the argument is just a plain object.

```js
function dataNoFunc<TAttribute extends string>(data: Data<TAttribute>): Data<TAttribute> {
    return data
}

const goodNoFunc = dataNoFunc({ attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['a']})
// WORKS: expected error on `subset` only - `d` is not part of `a` or `b`
const badNoFunc = dataNoFunc({ attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['d']})
```

However, it doesn't work when the `data` argument is a CIF that returns a function (that returns that plain object):

```js
function dataWithFunc<const TFunction extends (() => Data)>(dataFunction: TFunction): TFunction {
    return dataFunction
}

const goodWithFunc = dataWithFunc(() => ({ attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['a']}))
// DOESN'T WORK: expected error on `subset` only - `d` is not part of `a` or `b`
const badWithFunc = dataWithFunc(() => ({ attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['d']}))
```

Hovering over `dataWithFunc` inferred generics you can see the types of `TAttribute` isn't inferred at all (and ends up being a string).
I tried solving it by making the returned function itself generic as well (with the new `const` keyword) in the parent's generic argument definition:

```js
function dataWithFuncAndGeneric<const TFunction extends (<const T extends string, R>() => Data<T>)>(dataFunction: TFunction): TFunction {
    return dataFunction
}

// DOESN'T WORK NOW AS WELL DUE TO SUBTYPE ISSUE
const goodWithFuncAndGeneric = dataWithFuncAndGeneric(() => ({ attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['a']} as const))
// DOESN'T WORK: expected error on `subset` only - `d` is not part of `a` or `b`
const badWithFuncAndGeneric = dataWithFuncAndGeneric(() => ({ attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['d']}))
```

But that doesn't work due the common subtype issue (you can see the error in the playground as well):

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string'.
```

I'm wondering if this is solvable without having to specify the generic constraints manually (this is library code).

Comment: Constrained identity function. Best explained via this article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-write-a-constrained-identity-function-in-typescript

Comment: So when you say "when the `data` argument is a CIF that returns a function", where is that happening? When is the `data` argument a CIF? I see you passing in functions of the form `() => Data` which isn't a CIF.

Comment: It means the function returns the argument itself (which is a function by itself), just for the sake of constraining the type

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that answers my question. Can you spell it out to me? Exactly where are you passing a CIF as an *argument* to another function?

Comment: Anyway the issues here seem to be: you can't put a function in a `const` context (it doesn't have an effect, `(()=>{}) as const` doesn't work either); TS tends to widen function return types (see [ms/TS#241](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/241)); your `Data<T>` definition tries to block inference via an inferred `U` but that also blocks the `const` context. If I address all of those I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NB19zw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wow that works!! Thank you. TIL about the blocking inference trick

Comment: Now that I've posted an answer, do you mind if I edit your question to remove the but about "when the `data` argument is a CIF"? You are not passing in a CIF to any function anywhere.  If you do mind, could you please spell out for me exactly where that's happening? I think I understand what's going on in your question but not that part of the description.

Comment: I've edited the post and removed it myself. Is that fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) that is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a function like `<const T extends (() => Data)>` won't work the way you want. A `const` context only applies to certain literal values and functions are not among them.  It's like trying to use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on a function:

```
const oops = (() => { }) as const; // error!
// A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, 
// or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.
```

except that the `const` type parameter for function types just silently fails to infer the way you want, instead of issuing an error message like above.

If you care about the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the function return value, then you'll probably need to use a `const` type parameter that corresponds to that value, not the whole function.  Like this:

```
function dataWithFunc<const T extends string>(
  dataFunction: () => Data<T>): () => Data<T> {
  return dataFunction
}
```

But if you use that as-is with your definition of `Data<T>`, you'll fail to get the inference working as you want it:

```
const goodWithFunc = dataWithFunc(() => ({
  attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['a'] // error
  // -------------------> ~~~~~~
  // Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 
  // 'readonly "a"[] | readonly "b"[]'.
}))
```

---

Presumably your definition of `Data<T>`

```
interface Data<T extends string = string> {
    readonly attributes: readonly T[]
    readonly subset: T extends infer U ? readonly U[] : never
}
```

involves that [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) for `subset` as a means of trying to block inference of `T` from it.  That is, you'd like TypeScript to infer `T` only from `attributes`, and then check it against `subset`... if `T` is inferred from both `attributes` and `subset` then you'd always just get the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of both.

So you're attempting to implement something like a `NoInfer<T>` type as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829):

```
interface Data<T extends string> {
  readonly attributes: readonly T[]
  readonly subset: readonly NoInfer<T>[] 
}
```

But yours doesn't work because the conditional type is apparently blocking the `const` context as well as the inference, so `["a"]` is inferred as type `string[]`, which fails to match.

---

Until and unless TypeScript ships its own version of `NoInfer` (which might well happen with [microsoft/TypeScript#56794](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/56794)), there are various user implementations that work for some use cases.  Your approach didn't work for your use case, but there are other ones to try.

For example, [this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) says that `T & {}` creates a lower priority inference site for `T`, meaning that you can try `T & {}` to block inference.  If we try that:

```
interface Data<T extends string> {
  readonly attributes: readonly T[]
  readonly subset: readonly (T & {})[] 
}
```

then it suddenly works as desired:

```
const goodWithFunc = dataWithFunc(() => ({
  attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['a'] // okay
}))
const badWithFunc = dataWithFunc(() => ({
  attributes: ['a', 'b'], subset: ['d'] // error
  // ----------------------------> ~~~
  // Type '"d"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.
}))
```

So that's the approach I'd recommend, at least for now.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=5.3.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAxAlgDwAogE4Bc0QAbJAbwCgkk1h8JcAzBZAERHxAB4AVJCDPWAATKEij5ctAOZIAvOMkyAfOSrUkuCCGEB7YMQCeSDkoBGAV3pQAXJu16DxngG0Auuupad+o+ItmUBD4dnwCQqI0wIwMSACqSAD89j5O8e5IdsAQAG4M6gC+6owWwPCE+kjCHCAA6mj4ABYopfBc8PoSSGGCECJiElLA0soAFJ5VNS1lFcB2owCU8qrsnLzKC-NLcis162oa9vgWuMCTnNPlaPqFFOodwF3SurrC9U2X8ud1Dc2to4tlkhRpRDqYpJZrHYXAByEAwgA0SBhZhhbiRUACQRCSFh8LcSAA9IT+LhcLpcBNiUgALR0+kMxkM1QAPzZ7KpJJ4hhgyBhgxk7hhNDEwF0+BMUCgaGkoDMxGQ+F0SHwPL53kcfgARCAtRkAD4pTXGLVmPVuGEAOkKCwW6mp906ErMOnefzKX2qnDdlwB21UIJM+HMVmg0LhiORqPR-kCwXDwjRSAKtruFCKFFAkFgLFQmBaxFIoKi9CYudW3B6EQGSmGqmLXgcvmM4LQkLDRub3XcEw1XcxcZxfbSoz4ADJyCmMtSuHSkAB3CkAazEZmCpZVyvlungS6iMS0ZWQ89+uisSG3u5kSAeXQe9EEtzu1BKM2uZy9Pw+rXaTu6-F6fpFCGEZxkOT9LlmLYgQrdZNmBf0kFgnh617YITg-KZWlmJ9qFvCVnleH1Wk9GpiLKP0gRBCZW3bWxcQjJEUTRDEsXjBj8SJEldCXEBDBtO08L-F03l+T4FE-cj4EonZgQbIMQyhDjI2YmMB2xBMk2pBhyUpQ5qSZQyjMM1k2U5bo1WRLVhC1YU0FFcVJWlWUQHlRVlVVXkrN1JBDVNWzrWoFM7TuAogA)

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated comment! I actually didn't know about the `NoInfer` trick until you mentioned it.